# Unable to download file into live website of mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this function:

```
public ActionResult Download(string FileName)
    {

        if (FileName != null)
        {
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/uploads/" + FileName;
            byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = FileName,
                Inline = true,
            };

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

            return File(filedata, contentType);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The same Code working in local server but not in live server, can anyone tell me reason?

Comment: first place i would look is the `filepath`

Comment: You can try it with this way: Delete "string filepath=..." line and update "byte[] filedata =..." line with: byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + FileName + ""));

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain how exactly this is "not working".

Answer (score 0):

This may b not your answer but you can write whole thing in single line
using `return File(path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, name);`
file will be downloaded...(I used it in mvc4 and it works in live also..)

As example,

```
var audio_path = "/" + path.Substring(path.IndexOf("Content"));
String audio_name = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
return File(audio_path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, audio_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code for downloading the file:

```
#region Download File ==>
        public ActionResult downloadfile(string Filename, string MIMEType)
        {
            try
            {
                string file_name = "/Files/EvidenceUploads/" + Filename;
                string contentType = "";
                //Get the physical path to the file.
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath(file_name);

                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file_name);

                contentType = MIMEType;

                //Set the appropriate ContentType.
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (new FileInfo(file_name)).Name);

                //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
                Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
                Response.End();
                return View(FilePath);
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.End();
                return View();
                //To Do
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Still It's giving error page please check error on pic http://s32.postimg.org/unacqjlz9/Screen_Shot_2016_04_26_at_7_44_24_PM.png